# What is $E[T^2]$ of $T=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (X[n]+W[n])^2$ ??

Tags: probability, random-variables, estimation

What is second moment i-e $E[T^2]$ of random-variable: $T=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (X[n]+W[n])^2$,

Where $X[n]$ and $W[n]$ are both 'independent' of each other and 'stationary'. Moreover,
$W[n]\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$; however we only know the variance of $X[n]$ to be P (i-e $E[X^2]-E[X]^2=P$), and $E(X)=0$.

The first moment is $E[T]=P+\sigma^2$

But what would be second-moment $E[T^2]=??$

Need help !
Thanks.

Comment: For what it is worth, "if N is very large then distribution of T approaches" a Dirac distribution, not a Gaussian.

Comment: @Did From [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem),if N is very large then distribution of T approaches a Gaussian.

Comment: No. Correct statements of CLT would not involve $T_N$ but $\sqrt{N}(T_N-E[Y^2])$. Note furthermore that to declare that the distribution of $T_N$ approaches... a distribution **depending on $N$**, is meaningless.

Comment: @did For the purpose of experiment; 1) take 10 independent random variables of any distribution; 2) Add them; 3) Calculate the pdf of the summation, you will always get the Gaussian pdf whose mean and variance is equal to the sum of means and variances of individual random variables, respectively.

Comment: "Calculate the pdf of the summation, you will always get the Gaussian pdf" Actually you will not, except if the common distribution of the independent random variables you started with is normal.